# How To View If Internet Printing on IIS Server Is Enabled/Disabled Via Command Line

Tags: powershell, iis, printing, get, command

I am able to install and enable/disable the printing service on IIS. These are the steps for it:

```
1. Start the Add or Remove Programs Control Panel applet (Start, Settings, Control Panel, Add or Remove Programs).
2. Double-click the Add/Remove Windows Components button.
3. Select Application Server and click Details.
4. Select Internet Information Services (IIS) and click Details.
5. Ensure that the "Internet Printing" check box is selected.
6. Click OK to close all dialog boxes.
```

Now I am trying to view if this service is enabled or disabled using the "get-" commandlet on cmd/PowerShell and I have been unsuccessful, does anyone know if this is possible via command line?

Help is much appriciated!

Comment: The Internet Printing feature is a component of IIS, you can try to determine if Internet Printing is enabled by seeing if this component is installed. [`Get-WindowsFeature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servermanager/get-windowsfeature?view=windowsserver2022-ps) gets information about Windows Server roles, role services, and features that are available for installation and installed on a specified server.

Comment: Hi Samwu, thank you, I am familiar with the get-windowsfeature commandlet but let's say the feature is installed, do you know how to check if it is enabled and running? or if it is installed but in a disabled state?

Comment: By default, the Internet Printing component is enabled if you have installed it, unless you uninstall it, it will be disabled.